# Enum.each/2 returning :ok instead of a list

Tags: elixir

The function I have takes some table written in html and converts it into a list of 6-tuple atom-string pairs (e.g. "`...<tbody><tr><td> name: dave ...`" ---> `({:name, "dave"}, {:lesson, "dave"}, {...})`. I use Enum.each to iterate through each row and replace it with the correct values. The algorithm works but its not returning the answer it gets, it just returns an :ok atom rather than the actual data-structure. Maybe its my lack of understanding for functional languages.

I've read that the final line is what elixir will take as the return value but it's clearly not doing that. When I print the row inside the enumerator function, it's turning into the correct output. But if i do the same thing outside the enum each:

```elixir
rows = Enum.each(...)
IO.puts rows
```

gives me `:ok` again.

```elixir
#takes the html of table and returns a label-value pair for each students lesson from tutorful
  def convertRec(table) do
    rows = find_all_within_element(table, :tag, "tr")
    ## enumerate through table to find client-lesson info
    Enum.each(rows, fn row ->
      rowLabel = [:name, :lesson, :date, :time, :price, :status]

      row = find_all_within_element(row, :tag, "td")
        |> Enum.map(fn x -> String.split(inner_text(x), "\n", trim: true) end)
        |> Enum.concat()
        |> Enum.chunk_every(6) # 6 = length(rowLabel)
        |> Enum.map(fn vals -> vals = Enum.zip(rowLabel, vals) end)
      #for vals <- rowRecord do
      #  Enum.each(vals, fn {key, val} -> IO.puts "#{key} --> #{val}" end)
      #end

    end)
  end
```

I expect to run this:

```elixir
rows = convertRec(table)
for rowRecord <- rows do
      for pairs <- rowRecord do
        Enum.each(pairs, fn {key, val} -> IO.puts "#{key} --> #{val}" end)
      end
    end
```

and get

```elixir
name--> dave
lesson --> maths
...
```

but I just get the error that says "protocol Enumerable not implemented for :ok"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2), not [`Enum.each/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#each/2). `Enum.each/2` only ever returns `:ok`. `Enum.map` returns a new list.